# Hide div with jquery but can't work out the logic to target correct div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At the moment I'm trying to add a mouse click event listener on a h3 tag, when this tag is clicked it will slidetoggle a div.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
                <h3 class="visible-toogle"> >> Hide gallery</h3>
                <div class="galleria">
                    <img src="../Images/spherefactor_001.png" data-title="Sphere factor image 1" data-description="Sphere factor">
                    <img src="../Images/spherefactor_002.png" data-title="Sphere factor image 2" data-description="Sphere factor">
                    <img src="../Images/spherefactor_003.png" data-title="Sphere factor image 3" data-description="Sphere factor">
                </div>
            </div>
```

and here is my javascript

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".visible-toogle").click(function ()
        {
            var result = $(this).text();
            if(result == " >> Show gallery")
            {
                $(this).text(" >> Hide gallery");
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).text(" >> Show gallery");
            }

            $(this).closest(".galleria").slideToggle( "slow", function()
            {

            });
        });
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: replace `closest` with `next`, the gallery you want to show/hide is the next adjacent sibling of your clicked `h3`, not some parent of the `h3` (in which case we will use `closest` to traverse upwards).

Comment: Next works perfectly, cheers King king

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **next** in jQuery might help you

```
$(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow", function () { });
```

Answer (score 0):

Closest must be a parent. You need to use siblings there.

Answer (score 0):

Use "first instead of closest:

```
$(this).first(".galleria").slideToggle("slow", function () {
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87kas/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".visible-toogle").click(function () {
        var result = $(this).text();
        var hText = result.indexOf("Hide") > -1 ? ">> Show gallery" : ">> Hide gallery";
        $(this).text(hText);
        //slide toggle.
        $('.gallery-wrapper').find(".galleria").slideToggle(500, function () {

        });        
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nazmoonnoor/ejn3A/2/)**